# Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b})= \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ be two elements such that $a,b$ and $ab$ are not
squares in $\mathbb{Q}$

Prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b})= \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})$

Comment: Please make titles that are informative as to the **mathematical** content of your post, rather than as to your state of mind or personal desires and requests.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your post could use some improvements, and you might wish to look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Here's some simple improvements you could make. You should [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960), for example: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Can you formulate an actual mathematical question about your attempts? With just the bare imperative statement "prove that ...", you will attract downvotes.

Comment: Also [choose a good title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144), in particular "Make your title your question".

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 1):

Usually, to prove equality of sets $A=B$ you show that $A \subseteq B$ and also $B \subseteq A$.

In your case, here are the two parts.

**Part I.**

Let $x \in \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b}\right)$. Then, ....
and you conclude $x \in \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}\right)$. Hence, $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b}\right) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b}\right)$.

**Part II.**

Let $x \in \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}\right)$. Then, ....
and you conclude $x \in \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b}\right)$. Hence, $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}\right) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b}\right)$.

Please update your question or post comments about your progress.

Comment: i think i got it,  since  $\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b} \in \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b})$  the sum also so $\sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b})$ then Part II its ok.

Comment: and for part I  i got $\sqrt{a}= \frac{(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})+(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b})$  and  $\sqrt{b}=(\sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b})-\sqrt{a} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a}+ \sqrt{b}) $   Thank you :)!

Comment: @Mogul both make sense but how do you know that $\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b} \in \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}\right)$?